# Does iOS support time slicing?

Tags: ios

I am using pjlib and see there is a comment 
`//Must sleep if platform doesn't do time-slicing.` So my question is does ios support this? Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , it does ,

> Today, nearly all operating systems support preemptive multitasking, including the current versions of Windows, Mac OS, Linux, iOS and Android.

More about time-slicing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)